# Most efficient way to trigger wp-cron through system cron.

Tags: wp-cron, cron, linux

I have recently decided it would be best if i disable the built in wordpress cron function and move to the system cron which will activate the wordpress cron every 15 minutes.

I am wondering which way is best and what the differences are performance wise etc?

The two ways I have seen this done are:

```
curl http://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron > /dev/null 2>&1
```

and

```
cd /var/www/example.com/htdocs; php /var/www/example.com/htdocs/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Which way is better, and what are the benefits of a certain way?
Any advice would be great and appreciated!

Comment: Direct PHP should be a little bit nicer for server, but it won’t be a big difference, I guess. Do whatever is easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

Directly execute cron via CLI, either with the `php` command or WP CLI, e.g.

```sh
wp cron event run --due-now --url="..."
```

If you ping the cron URL with curl, then wp-cron will still have all the restrictions in place such as memory limits execution time limits. CLI PHP can use unlimited memory/time (hardware permitting).

Note that you will need to run the command for each subsite in the network

Comment: https://github.com/wp-cli/cron-command/blob/main/src/Cron_Command.php

Answer (score 0):

The official wordpress documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/ suggests doing it via a web request rather as per your first example rather than php CLI as per your second example.  Their example uses wget, but your curl request would work just as well.  I believe they are using the web request replicates the standard http requests that would otherwise trigger wp-cron.php.